# Laravel Ajax request not working of a controller

Tags: php, ajax, select, laravel, onchange

[image]

[image]

I am using laravel 4..2 and have a html onchange function like the image. And showing me the error as the second image.

This AJAX request does not work on create method but it works on index method of a laravel resource controller.

Its happening may be because of laravel controller. Can anybody help me by explaining this.

```
// Routes.php

Route::resource('index', 'IndexController');

    Route::get('ajax-subcat', function(){
        $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
        $subcategories = Subcategory::where('parent_ID', '=', $cat_id)->get();
        return Response::json($subcategories);
    });

// AJAX 

  <script>
          $('#category').on('change', function(e){
              console.log(e);

              var cat_id = e.target.value;

              // AJAX
              $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
                       $('#subcategory').empty();
                       $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
                      $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>')

                           });

                      //  console.log(data);


                      });
              });

</script>
```

Comment: Your calling `ajax-subcat?cat_id=`, however I don't see the route for this call. The route you showed is homepage.

Comment: Sorry my route is okay. This was my mistake. I have edited my question.

Comment: Works for me. Instead of the query result, try to simply return `$cat_id` and log it in the console. If you see the result correctly, chances are there's something wrong with the query result or the code itself. If not - are you sure Ajax even gets to the route?

Comment: what does console.log(e) output

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the dataType as json in your $.get function?

Comment: @AhmadSharif does e.target.value give you the desired value?

Comment: yes it gives me the correct value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel AJAX Request not working of a restful controller for a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892051/laravel-ajax-request-not-working-of-a-restful-controller-for-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

Since your using Laravel, lets begin using laravel to its fullest:

In Routes.php, please create:

```
 Route::get('ajax-subcat/{id}', 'SOME_CONTROLLER_NAME@SOME_METHOD_NAME');
```

the "{id}" tells laravel to store the details of  whatever comes after the "/" in a variable and pass it on to the specified controllers method. There is nothing more ugly than having ?ajax-subcat=cars in a URL. Also please replace SOME_METHOD_NAME and SOME_CONTROLLER_NAME with the correct names.

In your Controller, please add:

```
public function THAT_METHOD_NAME_FROM_THE_ROUTE($id){
  $subcategories = Subcategory::where('parent_ID', '=', $id)->get();
  return Response::json($subcategories);
}
```

And in your Ajax Script

```
   <script>
      $('#category').on('change', function(e){
          console.log(e);

          var cat_id = e.target.value;

          // AJAX
          $.get('ajax-subcat/' + cat_id, function(data){
                   $('#subcategory').empty();
                   $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
                  $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>')

                       });

                  //  console.log(data);


                  });
          });

 </script>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, just provides another solution of doing the same thing.

Comment: i dont want to just solve the problem, i want people to code in a more maintainable mannor.

Comment: The thing is, I don't think you solved any problem here, which is not what answering is for. This is a "I have a problem" post, not "How to do it better" one - just saying.