# Laravel AJAX Request not working of a restful controller for a method

Tags: ajax, laravel, get, controller

Laravel AJAX Request not working of a restful controller of a method.

This AJAX request does not work on create method but it works on index method of a laravel resource controller.

The first link is worked as it is index method. And the second link is create method which does not work. Both code are same

http://thetoppinghouse.com/laravel/public/listing  
http://thetoppinghouse.com/laravel/public/listing/create

Here you will get my code summary
http://laravel.io/bin/roYBY

[image]

I have already post this question without live example here but could not get solution.
[Laravel Ajax request not working of a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805325/laravel-ajax-request-not-working-of-a-controller)

Here is my AJAX code summary

```
// AJAX Requesst
 <script>
      $('#parent_ID').on('change',function(e){
          console.log(e);

          var cat_id = e.target.value;

          // AJAX
          $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
          $('#subcategory').empty();
           $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
           $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>')

               });

            console.log(data);


          });
          });

</script>

And routes is here

// routes.php

Route::resource('listing','ListingController');
Route::get('ajax-subcat', function(){
    $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
    $subcategories = Subcategory::where('parent_ID', '=', $cat_id)->get();
    return Response::json($subcategories);
});
```

Comment: I answered your question, but wanted to say a few things. We usually don't like it when code is just linked without pasting the relevant parts in. This is due the impaired searchability and the possibility that the external site goes down. Please add the relevant code to your question. Also you shouldn't post the same question twice. I'll let that slip because the other has become a bit messy and it might be better this way...

Comment: ok then I am going to edit my question and try to follow your suggestion when I will ask question.

Comment: By the way what do you think about my previous question which is similar to this question. I have think about delete but some one answer that get some point that's why i did not delete my question.

What should I do in that case ?

Comment: I just voted to close the old question as duplicate. If it will be closed the answer remains and the user can keep his points but no one else will be able to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your javascript code is making the ajax request to `ajax-subcat?cat_id=1`, a *relative* URL. This means:

```
/laravel/public/listing => /laravel/public/ajax-subcat
/laravel/public/listing/create => /laravel/public/listing/ajax-subcat
```

Since you already have your javascript inside the blade template you can easily let Laravel generate the URL:

```
 // AJAX
 $.get('{{ URL::to('ajax-subcat') }}?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
     $('#subcategory').empty();
```

Comment: you are great @lukasgeiter